# Vector reallocation regardless of reserve

Tags: c++, stdvector

Suppose that I have a `std::vector<Group> groups`. I am going to `push_back` a lot `Group` to `groups`. That is why I `reserve`. My question is that when I reserve `groups`, member `v` was uninitialized. But during `push_back`, `Group b` and `Group c` have different `v` sizes. Then can we say that reallocation is unavoidable when I `push_back` even though `reserve` called?

```
struct Group
{
    std::vector<int> v;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Group> groups;
    groups.reserve(1e6);
    Group b, c;
    b.v.resize(1000);
    c.v.resize(2000);
    groups.push_back(b);
    groups.push_back(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The size of `Group` does not change when you add more elements to `v`. `std::vector` stores its elements in dynamic storage it manages itself

Comment: `groups` won't reallocate. `v` for both `b` and `c` will however.

Comment: You have three different and distinct vectors: `groups`, `b.v` and `c.v`. Reserving memory for `group` have no effect on `b.v` or `c.v`. And since you copy `b` and `c` when pushing them, the vectors for the copies needs to be "reallocated", but it's not involving `groups` and its allocation. And since you reserved memory for a million elements in `groups`, as long as the size stays lower than one million, no reallocation should happen for `groups`.

Comment: *My question is that when I reserve groups, member v was uninitialized.* Can you explain this? `groups` doesn't have a member `v` since it is of type `std::vector`

Comment: "when I reserve groups, member v was uninitialized. ". That doesn't make sense. Do you mean the class member `Group::v` ? That doesn't name a (sub)object, and doesn't need initialization. Do you mean object member `b.v`? It doesn't even exist when you called `groups.reserve()`.

Comment: Size of a type is decided at compile time and it does not change at run time. Otherwise how would vector would manage at runtime ?

Comment: BTW: group[0].v (`b`) and group[1].v (`c`) will be (re)allocated since the push_back is done by copy...

Comment: I think you're getting confused between your 3 vectors in your example.  Try making an example that only has a single vector in that demonstrates your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The key thing here is understanding how C++ objects sizes work.

In your example:

```
struct Group
{
    std::vector<int> v;
};
```

An object of type `Group` has a constant size in memory. This is absolutely crucial. The compiler needs to know the size of `Group` upfront. That's why `sizeof(Group)` is a compile time constant.

Now.. hidden inside the `vector` is a pointer. Again, it's fixed size (4 or 8 bytes depending on the bitness). So your `vector` also has constant size. This pointer points at a block of memory which is dynamically allocated on the heap. This is where the elements are stored. Again, this block is fixed size, but can be reallocated, so the pointer might end up pointed to a new bigger memory block as the vector fills up. None of these operations makes either the `vector` or `Group` objects themselves any bigger.

When a `vector` fills up and gets 'bigger', the memory footprint of the `vector` object itself remains *constant*. However, the memory pointed to by that internal pointer (memory which is elsewhere, on the heap) will grow as needed.

So, when you call `reserve`, the `vector` knows upfront exactly how much dynamic memory to reserve. This won't be affected by many elements are in the vector within your `Group` when you add them. The element size from the point of view of the `reserve` call are fixed at compile time.